# Remove the last one array like [["1"]] by .splice() , why output = [[]] not []?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var arr=[["1"]];
arr[0].splice(0,1);
// arr = [[]]
```

Why I can't remove the last one array to blank ?

I need `arr = []` not `[[]]` when removed and sub-array (array in array) is blank

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/ehacof/1/edit

---

**Edit :** I just one to remove one by one like

```
var arr=[["1","2"],["1","2"]];
arr[0].splice(0,1);
arr[0].splice(0,1);
// arr = [[],["1","2"]];
```

I need `arr = [["1","2"]];`

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ehacof/9/edit

Comment: `arr.splice(0,1)`?

Comment: `arr.splice(0,1)`
you are removing the first item of the "inner" array. You want to splice the first item of "outer" array.

Comment: I want to remove one by one ex. `[["1","2"]]` @undefined

Comment: @undefined http://jsbin.com/ehacof/9/edit this is my better expend

Comment: Splice() returns the array without the elements outside the params, thus does not change the original structure of the array

Comment: How can I do , I have to use `if else` for check length of any main arrays ? @venimus

Comment: @l2aelba yes, there is no such method in JS that could help you directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splicing on the first element on the array which is removing `"1"` from the internal array at `arr[0]`. This code should remove the first array, not the first element of the first array.

```
arr.splice(0, 1);
```

**EDIT:** If you want to remove that inner array if it's empty then you will need to check it like this.

```
arr[0].splice(0, 1);
if (arr[0].length === 0)
    arr.splice(0, 1);
```

Comment: Ok , I have to check length ? Not any another js function like `.splice`?

Answer (score 1):

You removed the `"1"` from `arr[0]`, so `arr[0]` is `[]` and `arr` contains now an empty array : `[[]]`.
If you want to remove the array itself, splice `arr`, not `arr[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[["1"]];
arr[0].splice(0,1);
if (arr[0].length === 0) {
    arr.splice(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Array.splice` removes some elements and returns them. Your array of arrays will still stay an array of arrays.
2. The `JSON.stringify` converts an empty array: `[]` to `"[]"` and thus an empty array of arrays: `[[]]` becomes `"[[]]"`.

I added some more examples to your jsbin code to illustrate what your code actual does.

```
var arr=[["1"]];
var elem = arr[0].splice(0,1);

$("body").append(JSON.stringify(arr));
$("body").append(JSON.stringify(elem));
$("body").append(JSON.stringify([[]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use only splice to do the job, i could propose this:

```
  Array.prototype.removeOne = function(i, j) {
      if(this[i] == undefined) return this;
      this[i].splice(j,1);
      if (this[i].length == 0) this.splice(i,1);
      return this;
  };
```

Then use `arr.removeOne(0,0)`

First param is the main array index, the second param is the index of the subarray element to remove.

**Edit**: There is another way:

```
var arr=[["1"],["2"]];
arr[0].splice(0,1);
arr=arr.filter(function(ar){return ar.length});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your demo ....

```
var arr=[["1"]];
arr.splice($.inArray(arr[0],arr));
```

Comment: arr.splice($.inArray(arr[1],arr)); if you use this ypu ll see your answer...try it fast it works correctly...